# How do I scroll the Xcode version comparison gutter?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I cannot figure out how to scroll the version editor's comparison gutter and I cannot find any resource that suggests how to do it.

[image: How do I scroll this?!]

Answer (score 3):

This is not quite what you asked for, but you can access earlier revisions by using the drop down menu under the left and right versions:

[image]